# How Can I Clear A Kotlin Error in JavaFX?

Tags: kotlin, javafx

I was trying to fix an error in a JavaFX program from an on-line course.  In researching someone said moving a file cleared the error.
When I moved my todoItemDialog.fxml file it gave me this error even though Kotlin is not involved:

Error: Kotlin:  The Kotlin standard library is not found in the module graph.  Please ensure you have the 'requires kotlin.stdlib' clause in your module definition.

When I add the statement to my module-info.java tab in IntelliJ Idea is gives this error:
Module not found: kotlin.stdlib

I removed the requires statement and moved the todoItemDialog.fxml file back to it's original location but I still get the Kotlin error.
How can I clear the Kotlin error without starting over from the first line of code for this project?

Comment: Sounds like you have a configuration problem or installation problem with IntelliJ Idea.

Comment: I agree this sounds like a configuration problem. Is your project supposed to be using Kotlin in the first place?

Comment: Kotlin was not selected on set-up using Java 11.  Only JavaFX was selected.  Kotlin should not be part of the project.  I have coded many other projects, all without Kotlin as part of the set-up.  Somehow, when the folder was copied, Kotlin then seems to be required.  I am at a loss...

Comment: I started a fresh project and the initital dialog ran without error.  I made one change which was the refactor-rename the package name from (sample) to com.jonkreski.todolist6.  When I ran it again I got the Kotlin error.  While I seem to have isolated the error to one simple change I don't understand why it is happening or how to fix it.  My code snippet follows: package sample;

public class Controller {
}

Comment: It could _possibly_ be a bug in the IDE. You should [edit] your question with the _exact_ steps necessary to reproduce the problem (i.e. a [mre]) so others may be able to see what the issue is. If it turns out to be a bug then I suggest submitting a bug report.

Comment: After some reading I deleted my module-info.java folder and then in Windows 10 did a Ctrl-Z to undo the delete.  That resolved the error.  While that is good I still am unsure why the error occurred in the first place.

Comment: I had the same error.  I had moved the samples to their own model, view controller directories and that seemed to cause the error.  I used Shivani's solution (Build->Rebuild Project) and it worked fine.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered this same error while running JavaFX code. Simply rebuilding the project will solve the error.

Build -> Rebuild Project